Customising backref for enotez package
Since the endnotes package does not feature a backref functionality compatible with the hyperref package, I have switched to using the enotez package instead:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enotez}
\setenotez{backref}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    
Sample text.\endnote{Sample endnote}

\printendnotes   

\end{document}

However, while the enotez package has a backref option, it adds a hyperlink to the item number at the start of the note. I would prefer a hyperlinked ↩ symbol at the end of the endnote. Is there an easy way to customise the backref option of the enotez package to do this, or is there an alternate package that can already do this?

I don't how to do it with enotez (I haven't even tried), but this makes for a good example of a general mechanism provided by postnotes, so perhaps a postnotes solution might be welcome.
postnotes provides a general mechanism to store contextual information at the place of the mark and to restore it when the text is printed. At the mark the postnotes/note/store hook offers a place to store some variables and at that point the ID of the note is available at \l_postnotes_note_id_tl. When the note is being printed, the postnotes/print/note/begin hook is called, and at that point the note's ID is available at \l_postnotes_print_note_id_tl. So by means of the ID variables at the hooks, one is able to "connect" the mark and the text to pass around contextual information from the mark to the text.  You can use whatever data structure you prefer, the example below uses a property list.
With the data at hand (in this case, the backlink hyperref anchor/target), we can then disable the built-in backlink around the note's number, and make a link for a symbol at the end using postprintnote.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{postnotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \g_nullgeodesic_backlinks_prop
\newcommand*{\nullgeodesicbacklinktarget}{}
\AddToHook { postnotes/note/store }
  {
    \prop_gput:Nee \g_nullgeodesic_backlinks_prop
      { \l_postnotes_note_id_tl } { \UseName { @currentHref } }
  }
\AddToHook { postnotes/print/note/begin }
  {
    \prop_get:NeN \g_nullgeodesic_backlinks_prop
      { \l_postnotes_print_note_id_tl } \nullgeodesicbacklinktarget
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\postnotesetup{
  backlink=false,
  postprintnote={ \hyperlink{\nullgeodesicbacklinktarget}{**}},
}

\begin{document}

Sample text.\postnote{Sample endnote.}

\postnote{Sample endnote.}\par
\postnote{Sample endnote.}\par
\postnote{Sample endnote.}

\clearpage

\printpostnotes

\end{document}


